# How do you mix string literals with format operators on tmux?

Tags: linux, tmux, string, syntax

I know I can use some Format operators such as

```
#{=-2:my_format}
```

It will be a negative trimming of 2 , on my_format , such as say `my_format = prefix`

```
:display -p "#{=-2:prefix}"
```

It will perform that but. What about if I want to do a negative trimming of 2 of an arbitrary string such as `'my string'`

```
:display -p "#{=-2:'my string'}"
:display -p "#{=-2:my string}"
```

Neither of them wont work. How do you insert String literals on Format Syntax in tmux?

I have seen in the tutorial that you can operate with this syntax, basicaly assigning a string to a certain variable in this case @v

```
tmux set @v "foobar"
tmux display -p '#{=3:@v}'
```

Isn't there a way to do it directly with String Literals?

Edit1 : Reading through the tutorial I have found the following syntax.
To display a string literal on a format should adopt the following form `#{l:my literal}`

This has worked out with some commands , but still padding is not working such as

```
tmux display -p "#{=2:#{l:foobar}}"
```

Is outputting nothing